# Find element that is not inside specific parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to find an element that is NOT inside specific parent. Here is a sample html:

```
<div class="id01">
<p>some text</p>
</div>

<p>some more text</p>

<p>some more more text</p>
```

Ok, now I need to find a **first paragraph** that is not inside parent **#id01** and that is where I am getting lost. I started to do it like that

```
$('p:first').text(); //this way i would get the P inside DIV but I want to skip that one and count on next one that has no parent #01
```

Hope i made it clear.

Comment: [api.jquery.com/category/selectors/](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). All you need to know about jQuery selectors.

Comment: Naming a class "id01" is a little disturbing.

Comment: @dystroy Oh, that would explain why I couldn't get a jsFiddle example to work...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I also spent most of my testing time on this problem ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 :

```
$('p').not('.id01 *').eq(0)
```

Solution 2 :

```
$('p').filter(function(){ return $(this).closest('.id01').length==0 }).eq(0)
```

Comment: The HTML seems to call for `'.id01'` but the text of the question asks for `'#id01'`. I let you choose what you need.

Answer (score 4):

You could easily use the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector for that, in combination with `:first` .

```
$("p:not(.id01 p):first").text()
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypheH/1/).

Comment: this is really good and short but does it really detect THE FIRST paragraph? I mean without :first select does it still detect the first?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way, as suggest by adamb all this stuff is on the jQuery site, but here

```
 $("p:first").not($(".id01 p"));
```

Should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the .next() selector

> $("div.id01").next('p')

Comment: this does not answer the question in general.

Answer (score 0):

Use eq() for the index of `<p>`

```
console.log($('p').eq(1).text()); //some more text
console.log($('p').eq(2).text()); //some more more text
```